# How can I pass a value to multiple Pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How can I Pass id between three pages?

Page1.cshtml

**Purpose**: Display Product Details
Link to second Page:  `<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Entities" asp-area="Supplier">Add Supplier</a>`

Page2.cshtml:

**Purpose**: It is just to search Page to check whether or not the supplier exists in the system before adding to the system and Link to the product in Page1.cshtml

Link to Third Page:  `<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Supplier" asp-area="Supplier">Add Supplier</a>`

Page3.cshtml:

**Purpose**: Is to create the supplier and associate to the product in `Page1.cshtm`

How can i Pass ProductId from `Page1.cshtm` >> `Page2.cshtm` >> to `page3.cshtml` ?

Comment: just add `asp-route-id="@ProductId"` to the anchor tags

Comment: @LazZiya yes for the second page or for the search page, I am trying to get `asp-route-id="@ProductId"` to the third page, the logic here is when you click on Add supplier from page1 it will take you to page2 just to check if the supplier exist in a system if not exist there is a link in a page2 to create new supplier for and associate to a product, the reason im passing productID is to associate the new supplier to that product

Comment: What's the controller action method and the corresponding view code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe create a session that just stores the productid till you close the browser. Just to give you an idea:

```
//To set productid
Session["ProductID"] = productid

//To get productid
productid = Session["ProductID"]
```